# Uneven data size on some cassandra nodes after extending and cleanup

Tags: cassandra

1) We had cluster of 10 nodes, recently we added 20 more nodes to the cluster.

2) After addition we ran cleanup on all the necessary nodes.

3) In ring status "Effective-Owership" is properly balanced but "load" on two machine is different than rest of the machines.

```
rack1       Up     Normal  196.38 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  195.33 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  191.57 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  197.83 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  190.92 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  194.59 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  195.66 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  191.45 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  197.13 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  196.19 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  195.39 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  199.35 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  197.71 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  194.22 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  192.83 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  197.17 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  192.61 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  193.88 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  197.3 GB        6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  196.74 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  194.89 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  198.47 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  197.26 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  345.34 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  195.68 GB       6.67%   
rack2       Up     Normal  263.23 GB       6.67%  
rack1       Up     Normal  190.72 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  198.98 GB       6.67%   
rack1       Up     Normal  194.22 GB       6.67%  
rack2       Up     Normal  191.95 GB       6.67%
```

4) On one machine load is 345GB and on other machine it is 263GB while on rest of the machine it is around 195GB.

5) We are using Cassandra-1.1.0 and I have run cleanup on these machine twice but it is not helping.

Any Idea how could I balance this cluster with same load on each node?

Comment: Is your Cassandra cluster configured to use ByteOrderedPartitioner or RandomPartitioner?  You can find out by running cassandra-cli and then running the "describe cluster" command.  ByteOrderedPartitioner can have the side effect of uneven distribution of data across nodes in a cluster, depending on usage patterns.

Comment: we are using RandomPartitioner only and cluster data load was perfectly balanced before.Even now "Effective-Owership" is balanced but data load is uneven.

Comment: Is there any chance that something about your data set has changed such that keys do not naturally fall into an even distribution?  To clarify, consider the example of using letters of the alphabet as keys, words starting with those letters as column names, and counts of occurrences of those words in a document as column values.  This arrangement likely would yield an uneven distribution of data across nodes, because there are far more words that start with 'T' than words that start with 'Z'.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem of servers with way higher load than others.

What happened in my case is that bootstrapping failed for some reason, interrupting the streaming of data. When you resume it, the data streaming starts again from the beginning but the previous data is not removed and shows up in the output of `nodetool status`.

The easiest way for me is to just replace those nodes following this procedure for dead nodes : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_node_t.html

EDIT : `nodetool cleanup` just removes keys not belonging to the node, that doesn't mean it frees disk space.